# Listen to transactions on EOA addresses

Tags: web3js, transactions

Haven't seen any documentation that shows that this is possible. Could someone direct me to something that would allow me to listen to transactions on non-contract addresses.

Answer (score 0):

There are no events related to EOA in ethereum, what you could do is check on every block for tx of a particular account. You can also use an API like etherscan and periodically check for transactions of the address if interest in a range of blocks. See here https://etherscan.io/apis#accounts

Hope this helps.